# Explanation of port protocols in Wireshark?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireshark

When using Wireshark you can display the packets with just the plain number of the port, or with a "transport layer name resolution" (via the View/Name Resolution menu, for example).

Unfortunately, the resolved name are often obscure: "sentinel", "snac", "cimtrak", "exapt-lmgr", "jamserverport", etc. There are literally hundreds of different such labels. I assume wireshark is looking inside the packet and somehow identifying the type of communication it is. There is no documentation of these lables (cimtrack, etc) that I can find in the Wireshark documentation.

How can I find out what these port labels mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out what these port labels mean?

With an incredible amount of historical research. :-)

"Transport layer name resolution" is done using a file generated from the data in [the IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).  That registry dates back to the 1980's, and has some not-well-documented registrations in it.

There has, I think, been discussion of having Wireshark *not* use the "services file" to resolve port numbers, and, for example, just check for a dissector registered for that port and, if one is found, use the name of the protocol that dissector dissectors.

(But you'd still get those labels with tcpdump....)

Comment: So, if the labels are just hard coded port announcements, then I guess many of them are just worthless, because anybody can put a server on such ports.

Comment: Yes.  Hence the discussion of not using it for mapping port numbers to service names.  (The services file was introduced in BSD for that mapping *and* for mapping service names to port numbers; it's potentially more convenient for the latter purpose, e.g. `telnet {mailserver} smtp` rather than `telnet {mailserver} 25` at the command line.)